# Prevent the User from selecting any other option in Combo Box in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

The below mentioned was my requirement.

The user can select any one option from the ComboBox. After that if he tries to select any of the options from the ComboBox, I need to display a MessageBox which will ask the user to save the data for the first selection, with out clearing the previous selection.

Can any one help in solving this?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, but are you saying that if a user mis-clicks and selects the wrong option, they then can't correct their choice until they hit some sort of save button?

Comment: I would disable the combobox and show a "save" button instead of doing it this way. It makes it clear to the user that you need to do some other action before selecting another item.

Comment: Ron his suggestion is better, but if you really want to do it your way why not add a SelectionChanged event to the combobox and check if the current context is saved

Comment: @James, If the user want to choose any other option from the Combobox , but not for the first time.  I need to prevent him to click on any of the options in Combo. Instead I want to ask him to save the data for the previous selection.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. Although as James mentioned in your comment if they mis-select its a bad design. That aside here we go.

## Solution 1

Hook into the `ComboBox` event `SelectedValueChanged` or `SelectedIndexChanged` (preusming you are using Windows Forms) and in there, just do `((ComboBox)sender).Enabled = false;` so they cannot change it.

On **Save** you then re-enable it and clear the selection.

## Solution 2

To still allow the user to select and do the kind of thing you are asking. Do the following:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The last unsaved selected item
        /// </summary>
        private object mLastSelectedValue;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Make it a fixed list
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

            // Add some dummy items
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 4");
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the desired new value
            var newValue = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;

            // If value is the last-selected one...
            if (mLastSelectedValue == newValue)
                // Do nothing else
                return;

            // If this is a new selection
            if (mLastSelectedValue == null)
            {
                // Save the new selection
                mLastSelectedValue = newValue;
            }
            // Otherwise, the value is different...
            else
            {
                // Restore value
                ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem = mLastSelectedValue;

                // Show message box
                MessageBox.Show("Please save your work first");
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Save something
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");

            // Clear last value
            mLastSelectedValue = null;

            // Clear combo box selected item
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
}
```

## WPF Solution

Noticed the title states WPF... so here is the WPF way

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged">
        </ComboBox>

        <Button x:Name="SaveButton" Content="Save" Click="SaveButton_Click"></Button>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The last unsaved selected item
        /// </summary>
        private object mLastSelectedValue;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Save something
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");

            // Clear last value
            mLastSelectedValue = null;

            // Clear combo box selected item
            ComboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the desired new value
            var newValue = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;

            // If value is the last-selected one...
            if (mLastSelectedValue == newValue)
                // Do nothing else
                return;

            // If this is a new selection
            if (mLastSelectedValue == null)
            {
                // Save the new selection
                mLastSelectedValue = newValue;
            }
            // Otherwise, the value is different...
            else
            {
                // Restore value
                ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem = mLastSelectedValue;

                // Show message box
                MessageBox.Show("Please save your work first");
            }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add some dummy items
            ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item 1");
            ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item 2");
            ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item 3");
            ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item 4");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"preusming you are using Windows Forms"* The tags for the question specify WPF.

Comment: Oh didn't see that. Upadting example now

Answer (score 0):

Use select index changed event of the combo box and maintain a boolean flag for all the editable fields. If something chabged then set the boolean flag to true and check this boolean in select index changed event. If it is true in the event then show the message.